# Read ApplicationID with external software

Tags: install4j

We are building multiple setups with install4j. All of them are organised in one project file with multiple media sets.

We have an external software that should install the setups automatically. For that, we need to know about the ApplicationID, because all setup files have the same name.

Is there a chance to write the ApplicationID to the properties of the setup.exe? Or any other idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write such a file with two actions:

1. "Set a variable" action with variable name "appId" and script

   ```
   context.getApplicationId()
   ```
2. "Write text to a file" action with text

   ```
   ${installer:appId}
   ```

Comment: Hi Ingo, we need to identify the ApplicationID _without_ executing the setup. That's why I asked for the possibility to add the ID to the properties of the file or something similar.

Comment: Do you mean the Windows version info resource? There are a couple of configurable fields that can be set after selecting the "Customize version info" property of the installer on the "Installer->Screens & Actions" step.